# java move file to mounted samba share

Tags: java, linux, file-io, samba

Why can't I move files in java with

```
source.renameTo(new File(target));
```

to a samba share mounted to /mnt/foo (cifs mount in /etc/fstab)

I can use mv, cp with that share - it works perfectly.

The java code works on the local drive and is ok but it doesn't work with the mounted samba share.

Any idea why? How can I move files with java to a mounted folder?

(I only get a failed to move file (false) no exception ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rename method [documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) numerous limitations, including the possibility of not being able to move between different file systems.
It also points to the [move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method on the (new in java 7) Files utility which should be able to do the job.